# Set loglevel for application insights for an azure function hosted in docker and kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, configuration, azure-functions

I have an azure function which runs in a docker container which is deployed on AKS.
Application insights logs the request that happen but I have a lot of log.LogTrace("...") calls which don't get logged at the moment. When I deployed the same application to a regular Azure Function (so without docker or aks) everything got logged.

The following is my kubernetes yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-functions-secrets
type: Opaque
stringData:
  host.json: |-
    {
      "version": "2.0",
      "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
          "default": "Trace",
          "Host.Results": "Trace",
          "Function": "Trace",
          "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
          "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
          "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myfunction
  labels:
    name: myfunction
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - image: [dummy value]
    name: myfunctions
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secrets
      mountPath: "/azure-functions-host/Secrets"
      readOnly: true
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
    - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
      value: DEVELOPMENT
    - name: APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
      value: [dummy value]
    - name: ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES
      value: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup"
  volumes:
  - name: secrets
    secret:
      secretName: azure-functions-secrets
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: myregistrykey
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
  labels:
    name: external-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
```

Basically the question is, where do I put settings that would normally go in the host.json file?

Comment: After deployment do you see your `host.json` in Portal with the right contents? Goto your function-app ->App Files.

Comment: It is deployed in a docker container so i cannot go to the portal.

Comment: You could do: kubectl exec <podname> -- ls -la /<path to check> to see the available files. Don't know how to open the file, but im sure its possible